# Camel onException redelivery Clarification

Tags: apache-camel

So I'm a little unsure of how this will work.  I have a "Broken Pipe" Exception that occurs every now and then.  It triggers 2 exceptions to be thrown (according to the log): `org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException` due to the file not being able to reach its endpoint and `java.net.SocketException` because that is the root cause of why the file wasn't able to reach the endpoint.

So to deal with that I have an an `<onException>` block that looks like this:

```
<onException>
        <exception>org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException</exception>
        <exception>java.net.SocketException</exception>
        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="5000"/>
</onException>
```

So from what I understand Camel should select the `GenericFileOperationFailedException` and then try to perform 2 Redeliveries, 5000 milliseconds apart.

Well then what happens if it is unable to redeliver in those 2 attempts, will Camel then select the `SocketException` due to the nature of the error thrown?

Meaning Camel will attempt 4 total redeliveries, taking up a total of 20000 milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel will initially select on based on the order you have written them. "..the order in which the onException is configured takes precedence. Camel will test from first...last defined."

Straight from the documentation:

> So if an exception is thrown with this hierarchy:
>   + RuntimeCamelException (wrapper exception by Camel)    + OrderFailedException 
>          + IOException
>               + FileNotFoundException
>
> Then Camel will try testing the exception in this order:
>   FileNotFoundException, IOException, OrderFailedException and
>   RuntimeCamelException. As we have defined a
>   onException(IOException.class) Camel will select this as it's the
>   closest match.

So based on the example, I would assume that

> SocketException

will get triggered and redelivery started because it has an exact match and it is lower down in the stacktrace which Camel starts finding matches from.

Comment: Oh I get it now.  Do you happen to know if my error would trigger the onException block once or twice?

Comment: I would think it would get triggered once.